# Efficient MPS Description of a given quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, spin-chains, tensor-network

If we know the amplitudes of a (pure) quantum state wrt some basis, is there an algorithmic procedure to ensure an efficient [MPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state) description (one with the lowest bond dimension) of the state ?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if an exact MPS description with finite bond dimension exists? Or how to determine the best possible MPS approximation to a given state?

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm that explicitly gives me the MPS description with the minimum bond dimension for a specified accuracy for the state.

Comment: I believe this is outlined in Vidals 2003 paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0301063.pdf

Comment: You can do a sequential SVD, see e.g. Schollwoeck's review: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477: Sec 4.1.3 *Decomposition of arbitrary quantum states into MPS*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed by a sequence of singular value decompositions (or other minimum rank decompositions of a matrix $M=AB$ with minimal intermediate rank), where you partition the state first between position 1|2, then 2|3, and so on, and for each cut use the decomposition to find a, well, decomposition with minimal rank.  This is e.g. presented in detail [Schollwoeck's review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477) in Section 4.1.3: *Decomposition of arbitrary quantum states into MPS*.

Comment: Hi Nobert! The procedure you allude to above was helpful in getting things correct for MPS with open boundary conditions. Is there a (known) separate algorithm to do the approximation with a periodic MPS which will have smaller bond dimension? If there isn't, do you think this is even possible?

Comment: @Arnab I doubt such a decomposition does even always exist.

Comment: @Nobert Fair enough. But if I am guaranteed the existence, how would one go about finding such a decomposition? The rank of the SVD decomposition is more or less indicative of the partition entanglement; I am not sure how to distribute this entanglement between the two "paths" for a periodic ring. Maybe for motivation let me say, if I employ the Schollwoeck procedure for a cluster state on a ring, I get a bond-dimension of 4. So, I wonder if there is an algorithmic way of getting to the well-known 2*2 matrices (as components of the local tensor) corresponding to bond-dimension 2.

Comment: Guarantee of existence doesn't help. Otherwise you can just run the same algorithm and *test* for the existence.